# Class that checks for primes not working properly

Tags: java

I made a class called Primes for everything related to prime numbers. It contains a method called isPrime, which uses another method called sieveOfAtkin that creates a boolean array called sieve that has index values from 0 to 1000000. The user passes an integer n to the isPrime method. If sieve[n]=true, then the integer n is a prime number. Otherwise isPrime returns false. My problem is that when I tested this method using numbers that I know are prime, it always returns false. Take this line of code for example that tests whether 13 is a prime number:

```
public class Test {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Primes pr=new Primes(); // Creates Primes object
  System.out.println(pr.isPrime(13)); 
 }
}
```

The output is false, even though we know that 13 is a prime number. Here is my code for the entire Primes class https://github.com/javtastic/project_euler/blob/master/Primes.java

It uses a sieve of atkin, which is supposed to be the most efficient method of testing for primes. More info on that can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin

I'm not entirely sure what I am doing wrong. I have been trying for hours to figure out what is causing this error and I still get the same results (everything is false). Perhaps I should find a different way of checking primes?

Comment: the code works, i have pasted output

Comment: It is a waste of your time if you use a complicated algorithm like Atkin when a simpler one like Erothosthenes will get the job done.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code works like a charm for me, no changes done.

**code**

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {
    // This class uses a Atkin sieve to determine all prime numbers less than int limit
    // See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin
    private static final int       limit     = 1000000;
    private final static boolean[] sieve     = new boolean[limit + 1];
    private static int             limitSqrt = (int) Math.sqrt(limit);

    public static void sieveOfAtkin() {
        // there may be more efficient data structure
        // arrangements than this (there are!) but
        // this is the algorithm in Wikipedia
        // initialize results array
        Arrays.fill(sieve, false);
        // the sieve works only for integers > 3, so
        // set these trivially to their proper values
        sieve[0] = false;
        sieve[1] = false;
        sieve[2] = true;
        sieve[3] = true;
        // loop through all possible integer values for x and y
        // up to the square root of the max prime for the sieve
        // we don't need any larger values for x or y since the
        // max value for x or y will be the square root of n
        // in the quadratics
        // the theorem showed that the quadratics will produce all
        // primes that also satisfy their wheel factorizations, so
        // we can produce the value of n from the quadratic first
        // and then filter n through the wheel quadratic
        // there may be more efficient ways to do this, but this
        // is the design in the Wikipedia article
        // loop through all integers for x and y for calculating
        // the quadratics
        for (int x = 1 ; x <= limitSqrt ; x++) {
            for (int y = 1 ; y <= limitSqrt ; y++) {
                // first quadratic using m = 12 and r in R1 = {r : 1, 5}
                int n = (4 * x * x) + (y * y);
                if (n <= limit && (n % 12 == 1 || n % 12 == 5)) {
                    sieve[n] = !sieve[n];
                }
                // second quadratic using m = 12 and r in R2 = {r : 7}
                n = (3 * x * x) + (y * y);
                if (n <= limit && (n % 12 == 7)) {
                    sieve[n] = !sieve[n];
                }
                // third quadratic using m = 12 and r in R3 = {r : 11}
                n = (3 * x * x) - (y * y);
                if (x > y && n <= limit && (n % 12 == 11)) {
                    sieve[n] = !sieve[n];
                }
                // note that R1 union R2 union R3 is the set R
                // R = {r : 1, 5, 7, 11}
                // which is all values 0 < r < 12 where r is
                // a relative prime of 12
                // Thus all primes become candidates
            }
        }
        // remove all perfect squares since the quadratic
        // wheel factorization filter removes only some of them
        for (int n = 5 ; n <= limitSqrt ; n++) {
            if (sieve[n]) {
                int x = n * n;
                for (int i = x ; i <= limit ; i += x) {
                    sieve[i] = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // isPrime method checks to see if a number is prime using sieveOfAtkin above
    // Works since sieve[0] represents the integer 0, sieve[1]=1, etc
    public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
        sieveOfAtkin();
        return sieve[n];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isPrime(13));
    }
}

Input - 13, Output - True
Input -23, Output - True
Input - 33. output - False
```

Comment: I'm looking at the changes you made and it looks like I forgot to declare sieveOfAtkin(); in my isPrime method. I also made all my public variables and methods static. However I'm still a bit confused as to why this solved the problem. What makes a public static variable different from a public variable?

Comment: @slayer static did not made any difference, you forgot to call the `sieveOfAtkin();` method, so by default you were getting `false`

Comment: I can't believe I didn't catch that, thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
public static boolean isPrime(int number) {
    int sqrt = (int) Math.sqrt(number) + 1;
    for (int i = 2; i < sqrt; i++) {
        if (number % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This is a sieve of Eratosthenes, which is slightly less efficient if you are testing large amounts of numbers.